# Get Id of the first record in MongoDB

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have an view which consists of two parts. The first part is a table. This table displays data from a MongoDB database like this:

```
id| item 1 | item 2 | item 3
1 | value1 | value1 | value1    details
2 | value2 | value2 | value2    details
3 | value3 | value3 | value3    details
```

The other part is a list. When I click on details of one of the records in my tabel, a list appears with the data of that record, like this:

```
id    : 1
item 1: value1
item 2: value1
item 3: value1
```

This works fine. But when I go to this page, and I don't click on `details` the list stays empty. I want this list to be filled with the data of the first record of my table (without clicking on the details link).

This list is generated dynamic, so I use a loop to display the items.
So, if I click on details:

```
@Html.ValueFor(x => x.LineViewItems.First(lvi => lvi.Id == Model.SelectedLineView)
                     .LineFieldAttributes.Single(lfa => lfa.Name == fieldName).Value);
```

This code displays the value of the record. But if `details` is not clicked, so in the `else` part, I want to use the same code, but change:

```
(lvi => lvi.Id == Model.SelectedLineView)
```

to something like this:

```
(lvi => lvi.Id == "Id of the first record")
```

Can someone help me with this?

**EDIT**

My if / else statement:

```
foreach (var fieldName in Model.LineViewAttributeNames)
    {
        <div class="editor-label">
           @fieldName

        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SelectedLineView))
            {
                @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LineViewItems.First(lvi => lvi.Id == Model.SelectedLineView)
                        .LineFieldAttributes.Single(lfa => lfa.Name == fieldName).Value, null, fieldName, null)
            }
            else
            {
                // the code when details is not clicked.
            }
        </div>
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below, I moved the `if` inside the `First` statement.

```
foreach (var fieldName in Model.LineViewAttributeNames)
{
    <div class="editor-label">
       @fieldName

    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @{
            var selectedItem = Model.LineViewItems.First(lvi => {
                    var selectedId = Model.SelectedLineView;
                    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SelectedLineView)) // details is not clicked (SelectedLineView is not set)
                    {
                         selectedId = Model.LineViewItems.First().Id;
                    }
                    return lvi.Id == selectedId;
                });
        }

        @Html.EditorFor(x => selectedItem.LineFieldAttributes.Single(lfa => lfa.Name == fieldName).Value, null, fieldName, null)

    </div>
}
```

Comment: I did it a bit different, I have edited my question. I'm not able to convert your answer to my code.